# nvd3 eventclick option not getting exact point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 line chart. In that chart i am unable get the exact clicked point by user. I am using `useInteractiveGuideline:true` for tooltip. When i mouseover in single day it shows all the points in that date. When i click single point it return all the data in that particular date.

Here is my demo code : [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WbIe62ZcBbbuG00SbpLE?p=preview)

Chart options as follows

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        lines: {
            dispatch: {
                elementClick: function (e, scope) {
                    console.log(e); 
                },
                elementMouseover: function (e) {
                    console.log('mouseover');
                },
                elementMouseout: function (e) {
                    console.log('mouseout');
                },
                renderEnd: function (e) {
                    console.log('renderEnd');
                }
            }
        }, 
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 450,
        margin: {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 45,
            left: 45
        },
        x: function (d) {
            return d.x;
        },
        y: function (d) {
            return  d.y
        },
        duration: 500,
        reduceXTicks: false,
        useInteractiveGuideline: true,
        showControls: false,
        xAxis: {
            tickSize: 1,
            axisLabelDistance: 1,
            axisLabel: 'Time (ms)',
            showMaxMin: false,
            tickFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.format(',f')(d);
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
            axisLabelDistance: -20,
            tickFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
            }
        },
        yDomain: [0, 100]
    }
};
```

In the demo, in 3rd date i have a value 35. When i click that data point it will return all the data in the series.

[image]

In above console, how can i identify which data point is clicked. Please some one help to get the point data.

Comment: Hi, did you try using seriesIndex along with pointIndex in elementClick? Something like e[0].series['values'][e[0].pointIndex], e[1].series['values'][e[1].pointIndex]

Comment: @bgth how can i find its e[0] or e[1] ?. Once i find the series then i can find the the value by pointIndex.

Comment: You can try using seriesIndex in your object